# How to fix json_unquote does not exist error on production server?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to fetch the `candidate_user_id` property from within the `data` object from inside of my notifications Table.
This line of code worked on Local.

```
Notification::where('data->candidate_user_id', Auth::id())->pluck('data');
```

But in production, I get the following error:

```
json_unquote does not exist
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: maybe the server version is incompatible to use json_unquote reference https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78736, have you tried Notification::where('data->candidate_user_id as candidate', Auth::id())->pluck('data');

Comment: This doesn't work either. It just says server error.